# why jplayer playing on iphone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, flash, mobile, jplayer

i thought flash dont work on iphone and i been tring to see this jplayer on my mobile iphone 4 and mp3 is playing fine on it, so im scraching my head and thinking why its playing it?

so this means, this jplayer will work on all the browser and mobiles? cause im making site for playing audio, need to know.

**example:** http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-01-supplied-mp3/

> this is in flash tho, im really confused.

btw just to clear another thing is, even if its html5 it should not play mp3 file in html5 on iphone, because mp3 format is not supported by firefox.

list of format supported by browsers: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#reference-html5-audio-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because, jPlayer is HTML 5 audio and video player with jquery, Please check your link again and be confirm that it is saying, `"HTML5 Audio & Video player for jQuery"` not flash player

Comment: i tried on iphone and in firefox app and it not suppose to play mp3 files.. following is supported for firefox http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#reference-html5-audio-format

Comment: firefox is not playing mp3 via html5, check it's html, it is playing mp3 through flash player, http://www.jplayer.org/js/Jplayer.swf :) jPlayer place flash player in case of firefox

Comment: no, i was talking about firefox on iphone.. iphone dont support flash and mobile firefox dont support mp3, so how its playing then?

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 allows you to play video/audio without any flash involved anywhere. That version of JPlayer you are looking at uses HTML5

Answer (score 1):

jplayer only uses flash when it does not find a html5 compatible browser. please have a look on the jplayer documentation.
http://www.jplayer.org/0.2.4/developer-guide/